# How do you sort a 2 dimensional array by one column using cocktail sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have been looking everywhere I could, but I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

My teacher wants me specifically to try and find/apply a more efficient sort (more efficient than a bubble sort). I looked online and I found a bidirectional bubble sort, also known as a shaker sort or a cocktail sort. I looked for a way to apply this sort to a 2 dimensional array, sorting it by one column but binding the variable to the corresponding value in the other column e.g. `int[][] iCandidate = new int[CandidateID][CandidateScore]`

Sorting it by the CandidateScore and linking it to the CandidateID. I came up with this code but I don't know  what is going wrong:

```
package practice;
public class Sort {
public static void sort( int[][] array ){
    boolean swapped;
    int j = 1;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (int i =0; i<=  array.length  - 2;i++) {
            if (array[i][j] > array[i+1][j]) {
                //test whether the two elements are in the wrong order
                int temp = array[i][1];  //1 since CandidateScore is the second one
                array[i][1] = array[i+1][1];
                array[i+1][1]=temp;

                temp = array[i][0]; //interchange the CandidateIds
                array[i][0] = array[i+1][1];
                array[i+1][1]=temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        if (!swapped) {
            //we can exit the outer loop here if no swaps occurred.
            break;
        }
        swapped = false;
        for (int i =0; i<=  array.length  - 2;i++) {
            if (array[i][j] > array[i+1][j]) {
                //test whether the two elements are in the wrong order
                int temp = array[i][1];  //1 since CandidateScore is the second one
                array[i][1] = array[i+1][1];
                array[i+1][1]=temp;

                temp = array[i][0]; //interchange the CandidateIds
                array[i][0] = array[i+1][1];
                array[i+1][1]=temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        //if no elements have been swapped, then the list is sorted
    } while (swapped);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean count = true;
    int[][] array = new int[5][2]; 
    int col1 = 0;
    array[0][0] = 6;
    array[1][0] = 26;
    array[2][0] = 29;
    array[3][0] = 25;
    array[4][0] = 11;
    array[0][1] = 1;
    array[1][1] = 2;
    array[2][1] = 3;
    array[3][1] = 4;
    array[4][1] = 5;
    Sort.sort(array);
    while(count = true){
        System.out.println(array[col1][0]);
        col1 = col1+1;
        if(col1 == 4){
            count = false;
        } else {
            count = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please can you describe why you think this code is wrong? Please give the output for some example input.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.

Comment: whoops you are right

Comment: 1 minute let me just edit the post

Comment: You have posted code to print the output; I'm not actually going to try to run it to see what that output is. Please include the actual output in the question. And please indent your code correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that when you want to sort an array, so you have to keep in mind that you don't interchange two values, but two columns/rows. So, in this case, you just sorted the CandidateScore, but the CandidateId is now wrong, because you sort it afterwards. It's very simple to fix this, since you have 2 columns array.

To fix this, just remove the for (j=0;j<=2;j++) and add this

```
for (int i =0; i<=  array.length  - 2;i++) {
      if (array[i][j] > array[i+1][j]) {
          //test whether the two elements are in the wrong order
          int temp = array[i][1];  //1 since CandidateScore is the second one
          array[i][1] = array[i+1][1];
          array[i+1][1]=temp;

          temp = array[i][0]; //interchange the CandidateIds
          array[i][0] = array[i+1][0];
          array[i+1][0]=temp;
          swapped = true;
        }
      }
```

Modify in both places, and i guess it'll work.

EDIT: The code is as following:

```
public static void sort( int[][] array ){
     boolean swapped;
     do {
          swapped = false;
          for (int i =0; i<=  array.length  - 2;i++) {
                if (array[i][1] > array[i+1][1]) {
                     //test whether the two elements are in the wrong order
                     int temp = array[i][1];  //1 since CandidateScore is the second one
                     array[i][1] = array[i+1][1];
                     array[i+1][1]=temp;

                     temp = array[i][0]; //interchange the CandidateIds
                     array[i][0] = array[i+1][0];
                     array[i+1][0]=temp;
                     swapped = true;
                }
           }
           if (!swapped) {
              //we can exit the outer loop here if no swaps occurred.
              break;
           }
           swapped = false;
           for (int i =array.length - 2;  i>=0; i--) {
                 if (array[i][1] > array[i+1][1]) {
                      int temp = array[i][1]; 
                      array[i][1] = array[i+1][1];
                      array[i+1][1]=temp;

                      temp = array[i][0]; 
                      array[i][0] = array[i+1][0];
                      array[i+1][0]=temp;
                      swapped = true;
                }
            }
           //if no elements have been swapped, then the list is sorted
     } while (swapped);
}
```

Comment: I have edited the code as you suggested but it still doesn't work, it just prints out the array in the same order as the input. I will edit the question with the code

Comment: In the second swapped, the i most go from length(A) - 2 downto 0. You can see the actual code here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Cocktail_sort. The thing that I just added is the swapping between CandidateIDs. The rest of the code was just like you first had.

Comment: OkI have tried implementing the above code but it is still not working. When i try printing it after sorting, there is no change in the original array.

Comment: when you set it to print array[0][0] + "||" + array[0][1], (etc with the first column changing) the output is:
    6||1
    26||2
    29||3
    25||4
    11||5

Comment: @HaseebMuhammadTahir The problem is that in your explanation, you said CandidateId is the second collumn. Of course it wont change anything, because the program is checking the sorting of CandidateId and not CandidateScore. Just change the input: 1||6, 2||26, 3||29, 4||25 5||11. Or simply change in the code, the 1 with 0.

Comment: As you could see, in the comment i said     //1 since CandidateScore is the second one, the second collumn.

Comment: @HaseebMuhammadTahir you're welcome! Mark it as answered.